# Getting Error in Next JS deployment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

I am trying to deploy my next JS app on AWS Amplify While connecting it to my github repository. But while Building i am getting error in AWS build

Im unable to find what the issue causing in here because i am deploying on AWS for the first time

```
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                         # Executing command: npm ci
2023-12-17T15:59:41.765Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-12-17T15:59:41.765Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'bson@6.2.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16.20.1' },
                                    npm WARN
2023-12-17T15:59:41.767Z [WARNING]: EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-12-17T15:59:41.767Z [WARNING]: npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'mongodb@6.2.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16.20.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-12-17T15:59:41.767Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-12-17T15:59:41.767Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'mongoose@8.0.2',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16.20.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-12-17T15:59:41.768Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-12-17T15:59:41.768Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@14.0.3',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.17.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-12-17T15:59:54.384Z [INFO]: added 467 packages, and audited 468 packages in 14s
2023-12-17T15:59:54.386Z [INFO]: 37 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
                                 found 0 vulnerabilities
2023-12-17T15:59:54.399Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-12-17T15:59:54.400Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2023-12-17T15:59:54.685Z [INFO]: > quizapp@0.1.0 build
                                 > next build
2023-12-17T15:59:54.947Z [WARNING]: unhandledRejection ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
                                    at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src1537169919/src/MBG-Quiz/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/headers.js:32:30)
                                    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
                                    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
                                    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
                                    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
                                    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
                                    at Module.mod.require (/codebuild/output/src1537169919/src/MBG-Quiz/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
                                    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
                                    at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src1537169919/src/MBG-Quiz/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/index.js:63:18)
                                    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
2023-12-17T15:59:54.955Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-12-17T15:59:54.955Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2023-12-17T15:59:54.956Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-12-17T15:59:54.956Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-12-17T15:59:54.956Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```